# SQL MAX date in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the MAX function in my where clause because it is giving me the wrong data if I do not. Here is my code:

```
(SELECT 
Index, 
Company, 
FormType, 
MAX(DocumentDate) AS DocumentDate
FROM dbo.FormInstance AS F
WHERE f.company = 1234
AND (
    CAST(FLOOR(CAST([DocumentDate] AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME) 
    BETWEEN CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@StartDate AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME) 
        AND CAST(FLOOR(CAST(@EndDate AS FLOAT))AS DATETIME)
    )
GROUP BY 
Company, 
Index, 
FormType);
```

How would I make is say AND MAX(DocumentDate) is BETWEEN @Start and @End?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `HAVING MAX(DocumentDate) BETWEEN @Start AND @End` after your GROUP BY statement.
[HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) is essentially the WHERE clause of aggregation.

Comment: Do I have to put DocumentDate somewhere in my select statement? I am getting this error. Column 'dbo.FormInstance.DocumentDate' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Did you accidentally leave out the MAX() part of it?